# mmap thread safety in a multi-core and multi-cpu environment

Tags: c, multithreading, multiprocessing, multicore, mmap

I am a little confused as to the real issues between multi-core and multi-cpu environments when it comes to shared memory, with particular reference to mmap in C.

I have an application that utilizes mmap to share multiple segments of memory between 2 processes. Each process has access to:

1. A Status and Control memory segment
2. Raw data (up to 8 separate raw data buffers)

The Status and Control segment is used essentially as an IPC. IE, it may convey that buffer 1 is ready to receive data, or buffer 3 is ready for processing or that the Status and Control memory segment is locked whilst being updated by either parent or child etc etc.

My understanding is, and PLEASE correct me if I am wrong, is that in a multi-core CPU environment on a single boarded PC type infrastructure, mmap is safe. That is, regardless of the number of cores in the CPU, RAM is only ever accessed by a single core (or process) at any one time.

Does this assumption of single-process RAM access also apply to multi-cpu systems? That is, a single PC style board with multiple CPU's (and I guess, multiple cores within each CPU).

If not, I will need to seriously rethink my logic to allow for multi-cpu'd single-boarded machines!

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

PS - by single boarded I mean a single, standalone PC style system. This excludes mainframes and the like ... just to clarify :)

Comment: Your assumptions are entirely wrong. If this was correct, we wouldn't have a need for slow instructions like atomic increment or atomic compare-exchange, and concurrent programming would be a lot easier (and less efficient).

Answer (score 4):

> RAM is only ever accessed by a single core (or process) at any one time.

Take a step back and think about your assumption means. Theoretically, yes, this statement is true, but I don't think it means what you think it means. There are no practical conclusions you can draw from this other than maybe "the memory will not catch fire if two CPUs write to the same address at the same time". Let me explain.

If one CPU/process writes to a memory location, then a different CPU/process writes to the same location, the memory writes will not happen at the same time, they will happen one at a time. You can't generally reason about which write will happen before the other, you can't reason about if a read from one CPU will happen before the write from the other CPU, one some older CPUs you can't even reason if multi-byte (multi-word, actually) values will be stored/accessed one byte at a time or multiple bytes at a time (which means that reads and writes to multibyte values can get interleaved between CPUs or processes).

The only thing multiple CPUs change here is the order of memory reads and writes. On a single CPU reading memory you can be pretty sure that your reads from memory will see earlier writes to the same memory (iff no other hardware is reading/writing the memory, then all bets are off). On multiple CPUs the order of reads and writes to different memory locations will surprise you (cpu 1 writes to address 1 and then 2, but cpu 2 might just see the new value at address 2 and the old value at address 1).

So unless you have specific documentation from your operating system and/or CPU manufacturer you can't make any assumptions (except that when two writes to the same memory location happen one will happen before the other). This is why you should use libraries like pthreads or stdatomic.h from C11 for proper locking and synchronization or really dig deep down into the most complex parts of the CPU documentation to actually understand what will happen. The locking primitives in pthreads not only provide locking, they are also guarantee that memory is properly synchronized. stdatomic.h is another way to guarantee memory synchronization, but you should carefully read the C11 standard to see what it promises and what it doesn't promise.

Answer (score 1):

One potential issue is that each core has it's own cache (usually just level1, as level2 and level3 caches are usually shared). Each cpu would also have it's own cache. However most systems ensure cache coherency, so this isn't the issue (except for performance impact of constantly invalidating caches due to writes to the same memory shared in a cache line by each core or processor).

The real issue is that there is no guarantee against reordering of reads and writes due to optimizations by the compiler and/or the hardware. You need to use a [Memory Barrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier) to flush out any pending memory operations to synchronize the state of the threads or shared memory of processes. The memory barrier will occur if you use one of the synchronization types such as an event, mutex, semaphore, ... . Not all of the shared memory reads and writes need to be atomic, but you need to use synchronization between threads and/or processes before accessing any shared memory possibly updated by another thread and/or process.

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding is, and PLEASE correct me if I am wrong, is that in a multi-core CPU environment on a single boarded PC type infrastructure, mmap is safe. That is, regardless of the number of cores in the CPU, RAM is only ever accessed by a single core (or process) at any one time.

Even if this holds true for some particular architecture, such an assumption is entirely wrong in general. You should have proper synchronisation between the processes that modify the shared memory segment, unless atomic intrinsics are used and the algorithm itself is lock-free.

I would advise you to put a `pthread_mutex_t` in the shared memory segment (shared across all processes). You will have to initialise it with the `PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED` attribute:

```
pthread_mutexattr_t mutex_attr;
pthread_mutexattr_init(&mutex_attr);
pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mutex_attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
pthread_mutex_init(mutex, &mutex_attr);
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not sound right to me. Two processes on two different cores can both load and store data to RAM at the same time. In addition to this caching strategies can result in all kinds of strangeness-es. So please make sure all access to shared memory is properly synchronized using (interprocess) synchronization objects.